# How to send sigint signal to Android NDK processes?

Tags: android-ndk, signals

I am running a native method in a java AsyncTask that waits for a ctrl+c or SIGINT signal to finish.

This stop signal should be given from java, but `system("kill -INT -1");` in a second native method doesnt seem to have an effect when called through the jni. How can I send a sigint to the first NDK call?

Comment: First off, AsyncTasks are not processes - they're threads. A SIGINT in an Android process will bring down the whole app. Second, is AsyncTask taking a long time? Third, does it spend all this time in native code (as opposed to Java)? There's got to be a better method of sending an async poke than a signal. Signals are a blunt instrument.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanations. The AsyncTask calls a native method running until I stop it manually and yes it stays in the native code only. I don't necessarily need to use signals, it would have been just by far the easiest way to do it.

Comment: Is there a wait/busy loop in the native method? Can't you introduce a "please quit" global volatile variable, and set is from a native method in a main thread? Much cheaper than signals.

Comment: as far as I understand, there are no global variables in the NDK?

Comment: Sure there are. NDK code is in C or C++, C has globals. Look it up.